# Update Column Value for previous entries of row value, based on new entry

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTMvI.png)

I have a dataframe that is updated monthly as such, with a new row for each employee.
If an employee decides to change their gender (for example here, employee 20215 changed from M to F in April 2022, I want all previous entries for that employee number 20215 to be switched to F as well.

This is for a database with roughly 15 million entries, and multiple such changes every month, so I was hoping for a scalable solution (I cannot simply put df['Gender'] = 'F' for example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since we didn’t receive a df from you or any code, I neede to generate something myself in order to test it. Please provide enugh code a give us a sample next time as well.

Here the generated df, in case someone comes with a better answer:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
length=100
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(1001,1020,length),
               'Ticket': np.random.randint(length),
               'salary_grade' : np.random.randint(0,10,size=length),
               'date': np.arange(length),
               'genre': 'M' })


df['date']=pd.to_numeric(df['date'])
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True,unit='D',origin='15.04.2022')
```

That is the base DF, now I needed to estimulate some gender changes:

```
test_id=df.groupby(['ID'])['genre'].count().idxmax() # gives me the employee with most entries.
test_id
df[df['ID']==test_id].loc[:,'genre'] # getting all indexes from test_id, for a testchange/later for checking

df[df['ID']==test_id] # getting indexes of test_ID for gender change
id_lst=[]
for idx in df[df['ID']==test_id].index:
  if idx>28: # <-- change this value for you generated df, middle of list
   id_lst.append(idx) # returns a list of indexes where gender chage will happen
df.loc[id_lst,'genre']='F' # applying a gender change
```

Answer:

Finally to your answer:

```
    finder=df.groupby(['ID']).agg({'genre' : lambda x: len(list(pd.unique(x)))>1  , 'date' : 'min'}) # Will return True for every ID with more then 2 genres
finder[finder['genre']] # will return IDs from above condition.
```

Next steps...

Now with the ID you just need to discover if its M-->F or F-->M  `new_genre`and assign the new genre for the ID_found (int or list).

```
df.loc[ID_found,'genre']=new_genre
```